# R Shiny: Rendering summary.ivreg output

Tags: r, shiny, regression

I'm trying to render an instrumental variable regression summary in R Shiny

Here is the code:

```
iv=ivreg(lwage~educ+exper|nearc4+exper)
summary(iv)
```

When I use renderTable I get the following error:
no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "summary.ivreg"

Any suggestions how to go around this issue?

This is my website, if you want to see what I'm doing exactly:
https://ieconometrics.shinyapps.io/test/

Answer (score 3):

`renderTable` expect an object for which a xtable methods exist, you can see methods avaible with : `methods(xtable)`, and it doen't work with `summary.ivreg`, you can build a method yourself or obtain a result like these with the code below :

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(AER)
library(ReporteRs)

# define server
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$raw_summary <- renderPrint({
    fm <- ivreg(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + log(rincome) | log(rincome) + tdiff + I(tax/cpi),
                data = CigarettesSW, subset = year == "1995")
    print(summary(fm))
  })

  output$summary_table <- renderUI({
    fm <- ivreg(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + log(rincome) | log(rincome) + tdiff + I(tax/cpi),
    data = CigarettesSW, subset = year == "1995")
    data = summary(fm)$coefficients
    data = as.data.frame(data)
    # get signif codes
    signif.codes = cut( data[,4]
                    , breaks = c( -Inf, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf)
                    , labels= c("***", "**", "*", "" ) )

    # format the data values
    data[, 1] = formatC( data[, 1], digits=3, format = "f")
    data[, 2] = formatC( data[, 2], digits=3, format = "f")
    data[, 3] = formatC( data[, 3], digits=3, format = "f")
    data[, 4] = ifelse( data[, 4] < 0.001, "< 0.001", formatC( data[, 4], digits=5, format = "f"))
    # add signif codes to data
    data$Signif = signif.codes

    # create an empty FlexTable
    coef_ft = FlexTable( data = data, add.rownames=TRUE
                     , body.par.props = parRight(), header.text.props = textBold()
                     , header.columns = T
    )
    # center the first column and set text as bold italic
    coef_ft[,1] = parCenter()
    coef_ft[,1] = textBoldItalic()

    # define borders
    coef_ft = setFlexTableBorders( coef_ft
                               , inner.vertical = borderNone(), inner.horizontal = borderDotted()
                               , outer.vertical = borderNone(), outer.horizontal = borderSolid()
    )
    return(HTML(as.html(coef_ft)))
  })
}

# define ui
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  p("Raw summary"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "raw_summary"),

  p("Pretty model summary table :"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "summary_table")
))

# Call the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Victorp, this is great!
I also found stargazer() which gives me an output that I can render with renderUI. Your code diffidently gives me more options to change the output