# How to show summary from a dataframe in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Let's suppose I have the summary from a dataframe as such:

```
temp = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = 100, z = 1000)
 summary(temp)
       x                  y             z       
 Min.   :-2.07899   Min.   :100   Min.   :1000  
 1st Qu.:-0.62315   1st Qu.:100   1st Qu.:1000  
 Median : 0.11735   Median :100   Median :1000  
 Mean   : 0.09479   Mean   :100   Mean   :1000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.79622   3rd Qu.:100   3rd Qu.:1000  
 Max.   : 2.66509   Max.   :100   Max.   :1000
```

I want to show this in R Shiny in a pretty format? I've tried verbatimTextOutput and renderDataTable.

verbatimTextOutput kind of works if big enough. renderDataTable does not. However, is there a function for a prettified output?

Comment: Try markdown. Try kable using Markdown.

Comment: see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245173/r-shiny-rendering-summary-ivreg-output)